# How to match incorrect strings and replace by correct strings

Tags: r, if-statement, match

I have two dataframes.

One contains pairs of correct and incorrect place names:

```
place  <- data.frame(
  place_correct = c("London", "Birmingham", "Newcastle", "Brighton"),
  place_incorrect = c("Lundn", "Birmgham", "Nexcassle", "Briton"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The other contains a column with a mix of these correct and incorrect place names:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(town = sample(c("London", "Birmingham", "Newcastle", "Brighton", 
                                 "Lundn", "Birmgham", "Nexcassle", "Briton"), 20, replace = T), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What I'd like to do is match the incorrect place names in `df` to the incorrect place names in `place` and replace them by the correct place name.

**EDIT**:

I can do it in `base R` using `ifelse` and `%in%`:

```
df$town_correct <- ifelse(df$town %in% place$place_incorrect, 
                          place$place_correct[match(df$town, place$place_incorrect)], 
                          df$town)
df
         town town_correct
1   Newcastle    Newcastle
2   Nexcassle    Newcastle
3    Brighton     Brighton
4      Briton     Brighton
5      Briton     Brighton
6      London       London
7       Lundn       London
8      Briton     Brighton
9       Lundn       London
10   Brighton     Brighton
11     Briton     Brighton
12   Brighton     Brighton
13   Birmgham   Birmingham
14      Lundn       London
15     London       London
16     Briton     Brighton
17 Birmingham   Birmingham
18     London       London
19  Newcastle    Newcastle
20     Briton     Brighton
```

But how can it be done in `dplyr`?

Comment: Confusion? What confusion?

Comment: If you look more closely you'll see that I've already accepted an answer based on `dplyr`.

Comment: Okay, so why don't you present a simpler `dplyr` solution`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same `ifelse()` statement you have working in base R will also work with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(correct_town = if_else(town %in% place$place_incorrect, 
                            place$place_correct[match(town, place$place_incorrect)], 
                            town))

         town correct_town
1   Nexcassle    Newcastle
2   Nexcassle    Newcastle
3   Newcastle    Newcastle
4    Birmgham   Birmingham
5   Newcastle    Newcastle
6  Birmingham   Birmingham
7  Birmingham   Birmingham
8    Birmgham   Birmingham
9   Newcastle    Newcastle
10      Lundn       London
11   Brighton     Brighton
12   Birmgham   Birmingham
13   Birmgham   Birmingham
14     London       London
15 Birmingham   Birmingham
16  Newcastle    Newcastle
17     Briton     Brighton
18      Lundn       London
19  Newcastle    Newcastle
20  Newcastle    Newcastle
```

Or a `stringr::str_replace_all()` alternative is:

```
df %>%
  mutate(correct_town = stringr::str_replace_all(town, setNames(place$place_correct, place$place_incorrect)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this `multisub` function:

```r
place  <- data.frame(
    place_correct = c("London", "Birmingham", "Newcastle", "Brighton"),
    place_incorrect = c("Lundn", "Birmgham", "Nexcassle", "Briton"), stringsAsFactors = F)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(town = sample(c("London", "Birmingham", "Newcastle", "Brighton", 
                                 "Lundn", "Birmgham", "Nexcassle", "Briton"), 20, replace = T), stringsAsFactors = F)


multisub <- function(target, output, string) {
    replacement.list <- apply(cbind(target, output), 1, as.list)
    mygsub <- function(l, x) gsub(pattern = l[1], replacement = l[2], x, perl=TRUE)
    Reduce(mygsub, replacement.list, init = string, right = TRUE)
}


df$town_correct <- with(place, multisub(place_incorrect, place_correct, df$town))
df
#>          town town_correct
#> 1   Nexcassle    Newcastle
#> 2   Nexcassle    Newcastle
#> 3   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 4    Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 5   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 6  Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 7  Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 8    Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 9   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 10      Lundn       London
#> 11   Brighton     Brighton
#> 12   Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 13   Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 14     London       London
#> 15 Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 16  Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 17     Briton     Brighton
#> 18      Lundn       London
#> 19  Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 20  Newcastle    Newcastle
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:**

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but here is a solution with `ifelse`, after checking for match:

```r
df$town_correct <- vapply(df$town, function(x) ifelse(x %in% place$place_incorrect, 
place[match(x, place$place_incorrect, nomatch=0), "place_correct"], x), 
FUN.VALUE = NA_character_, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
df
#>          town town_correct
#> 1   Nexcassle    Newcastle
#> 2   Nexcassle    Newcastle
#> 3   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 4    Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 5   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 6  Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 7  Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 8    Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 9   Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 10      Lundn       London
#> 11   Brighton     Brighton
#> 12   Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 13   Birmgham   Birmingham
#> 14     London       London
#> 15 Birmingham   Birmingham
#> 16  Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 17     Briton     Brighton
#> 18      Lundn       London
#> 19  Newcastle    Newcastle
#> 20  Newcastle    Newcastle
```

Comment: Great solution. But what's wrong with my `ifelse` clause?

Comment: you will have to add one more layer of ifelse for NA to copy correct names to output columns as you are not telling it to what to do incase the name is already correct. You can add Correct names to correct names pair to your master list and it will work.

Comment: But doesn't the last bit of the `ifelse`clause `ifelse(match(df$town, city$city_incorrect), 
       city$city_correct[match(df$town, city$city_incorrect)], 
       df$town)` namely `df$town` say what do to in case the name is already correct?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these it makes sense to use `left_join` from `dplyr` package. You can use below code:

```
    df<-left_join(df, place, by = c("town" = "place_incorrect"))
    df$Town_correct<-ifelse(is.na(df$place_correct), df$town, df$place_correct)
    df$place_correct<-NULL
```